# How to Create/Show Multiple Iterations of Charts with the same data in One Area with Buttons using D3.js

Tags: javascript, html, button, d3.js

I have created multiple iterations using the same data. Consider this scenario (using the same data) the three different iterations are:

1) PIECHART
2) BARCHART
3) LINECHART

Now I want to be able to show all three charts in one DIV in my HTML template, but the user should be able to select which chart he wants to see by selecting options 1 2 or 3.

I have created my D3.js in a separate js script and told it to create the chart in the DIV with the id of "chart".

```
(var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")) /*line in app_d3.js that creates graph in div #chart*/
```

Here is my HTML template (with Bootstrap Elements):

```
<div id="chart"></div>
<form class="chart_form">
  <label><input type="radio" name="mode" value="size"> Mobile</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="mode" value="count" checked> Email</label>
</form>
<div id="info_chart">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button id="button_chart" type="button" class="btn btn-default">1</button>
    <button id="button_chart" type="button" class="btn btn-default">2</button>
    <button id="button_chart" type="button" class="btn btn-default">3</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I style my d3.js or html so that only the PIECHART is visible when I click button 1, and so on for BARCHART w/ button 2 & LINECHART w/ button 3?

Thank you,
(I am unable to share my data but the d3.js script is just the standard pie chart, bar chart & line chart)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how: http://jsfiddle.net/vnBsx/66/

You can use `$('#chart').find('#highcharts-0').hide();` or `.show()`. For the second and third charts you can use `#highcharts-1` or `#highcharts-2` as the default naming system for the charts` ids is this.

**EDIT:**

Here's the PURE javascript version: http://jsfiddle.net/vnBsx/69

Comment: Thanks! But that seems like a jQuery fix. Do you happen to know how to do it using javascript via d3.js? I can't seem to load jQuery in my Django project for some reason...

Comment: That link still seems like jquery lol but thank you nonetheless. I'll see if I can incorporate jquery somehow

Comment: Jquery is the $('something') codes. I didn't use them in the last link. Its Javascript

Comment: Ah, you might have sent me the wrong link. The last link still has the $('something') codes. I know what jquery is, mate lol

Comment: Sorry mate, I will send you the link asap.

Comment: No worries, I'd appreciate that very much. Thanks for your input.